# How to output ajax response from remote server to a text file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, bash

I am trying to output the response I get from a remote server (bash script, simple ping) to a text a file so I can output it line by line dynamically to the webpage. Currently, I have working code to output a text file to the webpage dynamically (`outputToPageDynamic.html`), I also have working code to get the response from the remote server (`testexe.php`). I just need to combine these two.

So I was thinking if I output the response from the remote server to a text file on my webserver I can output this text file dynamically to the webpage to the user.

Do you know how I can output my response to a text file?

Here is what I have so far:

testexe.php (get response from remote server):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .box1 {
        width: 450px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
    }

    .col {
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 2px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .col:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

    input[type=text], select {
            width: 20%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 4px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background-color: #ffffff;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gatewayInput">
<form method="post">
      <input type="text" id="gateway" name="gateway" placeholder="Gateway Name"><br><br>
      <?php 
        include("search.php"); //this does a search to auto complete
      ?>    
</div>
<div class="box1">  
<label class="col">Up/Down</label>
<span class="col">
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
  <label for="r1">Up</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
  <label for="r2">Down</label> 
</span>
<span class="col">
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit"/>
</span>
</form>
</div>
<script src ="../../../jqueryDir/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src ="../../../jqueryDir/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  //auto seatch function
  $(function() {
      $( "#gateway" ).autocomplete({
          source: 'search.php'
      });
  });

  //button click function
    $(".button").click(function(event){
        if ((document.getElementsByName("gateway")[0].value == '')) {
               alert('Gateway Required!');
        return false;
    }
        else if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length < 1) {
               alert('Please Choose Up/Down Value!');
               return false;
        } 
        else {
               //alert('Sucess!');
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url:"testexe.php",
            type: "POST",
                    data: {
              gateway: $("#gateway").val(),
              option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val() 
            },
            dataType: "text", 
            success:function(result){
                        $('#div1').html(result) //instead of send the result to the page i need to output to text
            }
            });
             return true;
        }
  });

</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

outputToPageDynamic.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<textarea id="target" cols="80" rows="20">Loading...</textarea>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkInterval = 1; // check interval, in seconds

var fileToCheck = "ping.txt"; //here I need to read the text file I get from the ajax output

var lastData;
function checkFile() {
$.get(fileToCheck, function (data) {
    // Update the text if it has changed
    if (lastData !== data) {
        $( "#target" ).val( data );
        $( "#target" ).animate({
            scrollTop: $( "#target" )[0].scrollHeight - $( "#target" ).height()
        }, 'slow');
        lastData = data;
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(checkFile, 1000 * checkInterval);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could just take the output from PHP and use the standard file writing handlers (`fopen()` etc) to create the file on the server when the AJAX makes its request.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sorry, I am still new to all this, I kind of know what you are saying. You mean when we get the response back from the server instead of feeding it to back to AJAX, we write to a txt file and use my `outputToPageDynamic.html` to read it and display? Can you show me an example please.